# How to choose operation point from precision recall curves for multi-label classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision-recall, decision-theory, multilabel

Is there a commonly accepted method for selecting an operating point for a multilabel classifier to optimize for each of these aggregate metrics:

1. micro averaged recall at some minimal acceptable rate of precision

   - *(for clarification on operational point selection/threshold selection for binary case: [How to choose a good operation point from precision recall curves?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7718/how-to-choose-a-good-operation-point-from-precision-recall-curves))*
2. micro and macro averaged f measures

I've found nothing on the matter except two papers that deal with **(2)**:

- "A Study on Threshold Selection for Multi-label Classification"
  https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/threshold.pdf
- "Threshold Optimisation for Multi-label classifiers"

  This paper goes into this matter for macro and micro averaged f1 measures. Every point on this PR Graph comes from adjusting only one of the thresholds at a time. (exponential computation in number of classes)

  Paper on Threshold Selection: https://pralab.diee.unica.it/sites/default/files/pillai_PR2013_Thresholding_0.pdf

  [image]

These sources handle problem **(2)** but not problem **(1)**